# Can we have variable width of Bars in timeline chart in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I have to show the variable timeline chart's bar length,
is their any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

series.timeline.marker.height / width is the options you are looking for.
It can be set at series scope, in order to get variable height.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'timeline',
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            date: 'Some date',
            label: 'Event label',
            marker: {height: 50, width: 10},
            description: 'Description of this event.',
            dataLabels: {
                color: '#78f',
                borderColor: 'blue',
                backgroundColor: '#444',
                connectorWidth: 2,
                connectorColor: 'blue',
                style: {
                    textOutline: 0
                },
            }
        }, {
            date: 'Next date',
            label: 'Next event label',
            description: 'Description of second event.',
            marker: {height: 75, width: 20},
        }, {
            date: 'Another date',
            label: 'Last event label',
            description: 'Description of third event.',
            marker: {height: 100, width: 30}
        }]
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/timeline.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: fixed it for type: 'timeline'